# Encrypt data, still able to do text search

Tags: encryption

If I use `rot13` crypto I still can do text search.
For example:

```
Query:           John
Encrypted Query: WBUA

Database Entries: John Smith => WBUA FZVGU
                  Jon Babe   => WBA ONOR

Result: WBUA matches WBUA FZVGU
```

**Are there more secure crypto methods (for example with a secure key), with that I also can do textsearch?**

Thanks

Comment: not yet really, but it's a field of ongoing research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible with secure encryption. The reason is really simple.

What you do requires that you are able to create the cypher text ξ(λ) of a small piece of plain text λ and then can find that cypher text everywhere where λ occurs in a bigger piece of plain text Λ.

When people do crypto, they attempt to reach so-called protection goals. One of them usually is that an outside observer cannot figure out whether the same piece of text occurs twice in the same message or even whether 2 messages stem from the same plain text. Therefore, ξ(Λ) is not guaranteed to contain ξ(λ) and finding ξ(λ) in ξ(Λ) doesn't tell you anything because it can show up anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @UTF-8, do you know another insecure encryption method? That protects the data a little bit better than `rot13`?

Comment: There are plenty of insecure encryption methods but I suppose you're asking for one which is easily searchable. `rot13` is merely one of the so-called Caesar ciphers. You can rotate by any different number ∈ {1, ..., 25} as well. `rot13` is the one best known, though. The other Caesar ciphers also share the property of being searchable. If what you're searching for is very short, the Vigenère cipher is searchable as well but you have to try different possible ξ(λ). The Vigenère cipher has been thought to be secure for centuries. You can see how it gets harder when better crypto is used.

Comment: @Acapulco by now has posted their answer linking to a Wikipedia article describing that this is a problem for which a solution is hard to find. For simply the purpose of searching through text, it's probably best to just encrypt it and search for the text once you got the plain text. Note that this can usually be done without decrypting everything first. Instead, a part can be decrypted and searched while the rest is still being decrypted. This not only can give you the first results soon but also means that you don't need to write all the plain text data onto a storage medium first.

Comment: @JohnSmith To be clear, Vigenere was indeed thought secure for centuries, but it has now been known broken for a century and a half, so it is not _actuallly_ secure.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 And when I first heard of it in the first lecture of a university course about security, the professor said in advance that it was thought to be secure for centuries and before he could explain how it worked (the slide was already visible), pretty much every single person in the room broke out in laughter, not believing that people could be dumb enough not to instantly see how easy it is to break the Vigenère cipher.

Comment: @UTF-8 That could be only because it's now a well-known fact. If you showed one of those the cipher and asked them *how* to break it, they wouldn't have a clue.

Comment: What is a well-known fact? That it can be broken? That doesn't help you with figuring out how it can be broken and when breaking a cipher, one of course always assumes it can be broken. People back then knew how to break Caesar and from there, breaking Vigenère shouldn't take a significant amount of thinking. Besides, I doubt many of the students learned how to break it before taking that lecture (me and my friends didn't), it wasn't explained in the lecture how it can be broken because it's so obvious, and breaking it was part of the very first exercise sheet where everything is really easy.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the technique you are looking for is called [Fully homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Fully_homomorphic_encryption)

Such a system lets you use encrypted inputs to do arbitrary operations on encrypted data while returning an encrypted output.

The current problem is that operations on FHE systems are terribly slow.

Comment: An other problem with FHE systems is that the fundamental operations they support aren't typically the search operation, so you'd have to implement that using the other operations which means that a simple text search becomes a sequence of a lot of other operations, each of these is terribly slow.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative could be to use a **search index** (inverted index).

Index the data before encryption. Then encrypt the index.

You have to decrypt the index before performing the search, but the index could be much smaller than the data. Also, depending on the index technique, only parts of the index may need to be decrypted.

(This approach may not be efficient if the text in the database is frequently updated.)

Sample index (abstraction):

```
Word    Record#
----    --------
anders  245,354
babe    181
bill    133,354
david   201,245
john    139
jon     181,310
niven   201
smith   133,139,310
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What encryption algorithm should I use? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. It partly depends on the chosen indexing technique. I suspect one alternative could be to have the index in a small db in an encrypted directory. While the db manager reads and writes disk blocks the cryptfilesystem will encrypt and decrypt the blocks. The db access would be in clear text. That way the encryption keys are kept in a well tested component near the os, and not in your application. (I am not versed to recommend a particular directory level filesystem encryption or a database manager. I guess any would do.)